# Сохранение путей файлов при сборке в Pelican

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

### 1. Цель

Положим, используя генератор статических сайтов Pelican, пишу статью (если быть точным, `page`; в Pelican это не совсем то, что `article`, но всё равно более подходящим мне представляется термин `статья`, а не `страница`) в Markdown. Файл статьи находится по пути `/pages/myfolder/myarticle.md`. Нужно, чтобы после компиляции Markdown в HTML, не терялись бы пути, по которым располагаются файлы, — в данном случае `myfolder`, — и output бы выглядел так: `myfolder/myarticle.html`.

---

### 2. Желаемое поведение

Структура моей папки `content`, где пишу статьи в Markdown:

```
└───pages
    ├───Life-hacks
    │       Neobyknovennaya.md
    │       Sasha-Idealna.md
    │
    └───Sublime Text
            Sasha-Bozhestvenna.md
```

Структура моей папки `output`, куда компилируются статьи, написанные в Markdown.

```
└───pages
    ├───Life-hacks
    │       Neobyknovennaya.html
    │       Sasha-Idealna.html
    │
    └───Sublime Text
            Sasha-Bozhestvenna.html
```

---

### 3. Актуальное поведение

Сейчас папка `output` выглядит так:

```
├───pages
│       Neobyknovennaya.html
│       Sasha-Bozhestvenna.html
│       Sasha-Idealna.html
```

Папки `Life-hacks` и `Sublime Text` пропали при сборке.

---

### 4. мои настройки

Часть моего файла `publishconf.py`:

```python
USE_FOLDER_AS_CATEGORY = True
PAGE_URL = '{slug}.html'
PAGE_SAVE_AS = PAGE_URL
CATEGORY_URL = '{slug}/index.html'
CATEGORY_SAVE_AS = CATEGORY_URL
```

---

### 5. Шаги для воспроизведения

Установил через `pip` пакеты `pelican` и `markdown` → запускаю терминал, находясь в корневой папке тестового сайта, → ввожу в терминал команду `pelican content` → получаю актуальное поведение, не желаемое поведение.

---

### 6. Не помогло

1. В разделе [**URL Settings**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/settings.html#url-settings) документации Pelican, — где как раз описывается, как будет выглядеть URL сайта, — не нашёл какой-либо переменной, включающей имена путей.
2. Нагуглил [**ответ на похожий вопрос**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930000/5951529), но конфигурация, предложенная автором ответа, не помогла. Получаю такое же поведение.
3. Просматривал [**список сайтов, сделанных на Pelican**](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/wiki/Powered-by-Pelican), однако не довелось найти ни одного с нужной мне структурой папок.

---

### 7. Не предлагать

1. Просьба не давать неаргументированные комментарии вида `юзай $другой генератор сайтов$`.
2. Да, знаю, что к статьям в Pelican можно проставлять теги и категории, но необходимо, чтобы имена папок содержались и в URL.

---

### 8. Программно-аппаратное окружение

**Операционная система:**
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN
**Python:**
3.6.0
**Pelican:**
3.7.1

Comment: А я чего-то не понял, почему всё-таки page, а не article?

Comment: @andreymal, насколько я понял из [**документации**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/content.html#articles-and-pages), `articles` в отличие от `pages`, связаны с датой. я не собираюсь использовать дату в URL, осуществлять сортировку по дате, писать на сайте статьи новостного характера

Comment: или прочие [**временно актуальные материалы**](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B#.D0.93.D0.B4.D0.B5_.D0.BD.D0.B5_.D0.B8.D1.89.D0.B5.D1.82_.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BA_.D0.9A.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.82.D1.8B) и т. д. Спасибо.

Comment: Лично я просто проставляю дату по умолчанию и всюду её игнорирую и не парюсь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покопался в исходниках Pelican и обнаружил у класса `Page` две любопытные вещи `override_url` и `override_save_as` — путём их переопределения можно писать файлы куда угодно. После этого родился такой плагин (про их написание есть в [документации](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/plugins.html)):

*Файл с настройками pelicanconf.py*

```
PLUGINS = ['pagefixer']
```

*Сам плагин pagefixer.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from itertools import chain
from pelican import signals

def fix_pages(generator):
    for page in chain(generator.translations, generator.pages,
            generator.hidden_translations, generator.hidden_pages):
        # Получаем путь исходника относительно каталога content
        new_path = page.get_relative_source_path()
        # Заменяем расширение на html
        new_path = new_path.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.html'
        # И пихаем в страницу вместо родных путей относительно output
        page.override_url = new_path
        page.override_save_as = new_path

def register():
    signals.page_generator_finalized.connect(fix_pages)
```

И таким образом получаем нужные нам пути.

Внутренние ссылки вида `[текст]({filename}../pages/foo/bar.md)` тоже работают правильно и учитывают любые изменения в `override_url`.

P.S.1. Никогда раньше не писал плагинов к Pelican, так что конструктивные тапки принимаются

P.S.2. Не проверял, как оно работает на Windows, может быть там обратные слэши используются, в таком случае надо будет приписать `import os; new_path = new_path.replace(os.path.sep, '/')` или что-то типа того

Comment: Ого! И в Windows работает.

Comment: andreymal, всё равно относительные ссылки посредством `{filename}` можно создавать только на файлы из папки `content`. А можно ли делать относительные ссылки на файлы из других папок директории с сайтом, например, `themes`? [**Тут подробности**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41845037/5951529) этого вопроса, я который недавно задавал. Спасибо.

Comment: Думается, необходимость в ссылках за пределы `content` указывает на косяк в архитектуре и лучше от этой надобности избавиться, контенту не следует быть привязанным к конкретной теме

Comment: andreymal, как тогда лучше поступить? Переносить изображения, css, скрипты в `content`? Но тогда такая проблема: эти файлы будут дублироваться в `output`. Т. к. в них нет переменных, не понимаю, зачем создавать столько дубликатов, которые будут только мешать. Спасибо.

Comment: Зависит от цели, которую я при беглой пробежке по исходникам сайта не совсем понял. Хотя подозреваю, что тут будут к месту блоки-шаблоны подобно какой-нибудь википедии, но как их сделать в Pelican я сходу не нашёл, так что теперь наверно я уже не помощник

Comment: andreymal, в исходниках только тестирую возможности Pelican, чтобы перенести потом настоящий сайт. «Блоки-шаблоны подобно какой-нибудь википедии» вряд ли буду использовать :) . Однако неплохо было бы просто ссылаться в статьях, написанных в Markdown, на изображения. Причём достаточно редко, поскольку изображения, в основном, хранятся на внешнем хостинге. Но что-нибудь вроде `![Описание изображения]({{SITEURL}}/themes/mytheme/path/to/my/image.svg)` иметь было бы неплохо. Спасибо.

Comment: Изображения, относящиеся к статьям, должны быть в `content`. Изображения, относящиеся к интерфейсу (иконка `i` для примечания, кнопочки копирования/вставки и т. п.) должны реализовываться через CSS или таки «блоки-шаблоны» прописанные в теме, а контент должен их использовать неявно. Но как это всё грамотно делать в Pelican, я не знаю

Comment: `Изображения, относящиеся к статьям, должны быть в content.` — И дублироваться в `output`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52478/discussion-between-andreymal-and--), а то это уже не по теме ни вопроса, ни ответа

Comment: Жаль, другие плагины не хотят указывать правильные пути. Допустим, пользуюсь плагином, который позволяет добавлять кастомные CSS- и JavaScript-файлы к отдельным страницам, но [**пути к файлам при сборке некорректные**](https://github.com/mortada/pelican_javascript/issues/3). Приходится [**писать «костыли»**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/master/Makefile#L69). Спасибо.

Comment: andreymal, могли бы Вы [**добавить**](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/blob/master/Contributing.rst) Ваш плагин в список плагинов Pelican? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Решение

Проблема разрешаема.

Следует указывать папку в [**переменной Slug**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/themes.html#page) Markdown-страницы. Например, в метаданных файла `SashaIdealna.md` должно внести строку `Slug: Life-hacks\Sasha-Idealna` → файл `Sasha-Idealna.html` будет располагаться в папке `Life-hacks` и после компиляции.

---

### 2. Недостаток

Придётся указывать папки в метаданных каждой статьи/страницы, которую написали, — что время не экономит. Если кто-то знает более удобный способ, когда следует 1 раз что-то изменить в конфигурации, отпишитесь, Ваш ответ будет принят.