# Копирование всех файлов из папки в другую папку при сборке в Pelican

Tags: python, pelican

### 1. Цель

Не получается найти, как при сборке проекта в Pelican можно вывести сразу все файлы из директории в корень папки, куда осуществляется вывод.

У меня получается выводить файлы по отдельности, но не когда их много.

---

### 2. Обоснование

Положим, я [**сгенерировал иконки для всех браузеров и платформ**](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). Их нужно обязательно располагать в корневой папке сайта. Но при навигации по корневой папке сайта иконки мешают, пример:

[image: Фавиконы]

Неплохо было бы убрать их в отдельную папку, а уже чтобы при сборке они располагались там, где следует. На прописывание в `pelicanconf.py` каждой иконки по отдельности может уйти время, если их много.

Обоснование цели — хочется порядка в исходниках. На практике неплохо было бы поместить в отдельную папку не только фавиконы, о которых речь в примере, но и другие файлы.

---

### 3. Желаемое поведение

Использую названия директорий по умолчанию:

- `content` — папка с контентом сайта;
- `output` — папка, куда производится вывод.

В директории `content/favicons` имеются файлы `favicon.ico` и `favicon1.ico`. Необходимо, чтобы при сборке все файлы папки `favicons` оказались в корне директории `output`.

---

### 4. Настройки

Часть моего файла `pelicanconf.py`:

```python
STATIC_PATHS = ['']
STATIC_EXCLUDES = ['Example Sasha Folder']
```

Для сохранения путей файлов при сборке пользуюсь [**плагином от andreymal**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619397/199934).

---

### 5. Не помогло

1. Каждый файл по отдельности можно вывести при помощи параметра [**EXTRA_PATH_METADATA**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/settings.html#basic-settings). Пример:

   ```python
   EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {
       'favicons/favicon.ico': {'path': 'favicon.ico'},
       'favicons/favicon1.ico': {'path': 'favicon1.ico'},
   }
   ```

   При сборке файлы `favicon.ico` и `favicon1.ico` окажутся в корне директории `output`. Однако для папок в целом это не работает. Пробовал варианты вроде

   ```python
   EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {
       'favicons': {'path': ''},
   }
   ```

   Безуспешно.
2. В документации [**нашёл примеры только для файлов**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=EXTRA_PATH_METADATA#metadata), но не директорий.
3. Осуществлял [**поиск по репозиториям на GitHub**](https://github.com/search?q=EXTRA_PATH_METADATA&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) по ключевому слову `EXTRA_PATH_METADATA`  — не нашёл нужной для меня конфигурации.

Comment: Если нужно переносить всё содержимое каталога на уровень выше, то по-моему что-то делается не так, зачем это?

Comment: @andreymal: спасибо за комментарий. Дополнил, [**зачем это нужно**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/640181/revisions).